# Change turtle context into patch context to color patches

Tags: colors, patch, netlogo

A table is written in turtle context with values between 0 and 1 and patchID as keys. Each patch should be colored according to the value in the table with scale-color. The result should look sth. like the heat diffusion model in the library. So far, it only colors the patches my turtles are located on. I guess I need to write the table from turtle to patch context, but have no idea how this should be done. Does Netlogo provide any option for that? Thanks!

```
   clear-links 
   let alone turtles with [not any? link-neighbors] 
   ask turtles[
   let res2 one-of other alone 

   ;;go over each patch
   foreach table:keys dict_Opinion[ 
   ;;get current opinion for both agents and store it op_a1  and op_a2 
   let op_a1 table:get dict_Opinion ?    
   let op_a2 [table:get dict_Opinion ?] of res2    

   let soc-dist 0
   let new_op_a1 0
   let new_op_a2 0

   ;;calculate social distance
   set soc-dist abs(op_a1 - op_a2)  

   ;;check if social distance is less than threshold D
   ifelse soc-dist < updated_D [

   ;;if lower than D calculate new opinions for both agents           
   set new_op_a1 (op_a1 + (mu * ( op_a1 - op_a2)))
   if new_op_a1 > 1 [set new_op_a1 1]
   if new_op_a1 < 0 [set new_op_a1 0]             
   set new_op_a2 (op_a2 + (mu * ( op_a2 - op_a1)))
   if new_op_a2 > 1 [set new_op_a2 1]
   if new_op_a2 < 0 [set new_op_a2 0] ]

   ;;else: if the soc distance is too large  opinions remain unchanged       
   [set new_op_a1 op_a1
   set new_op_a2 op_a2]    

   ;;newly calculated opinions are put in the opinion lists of the agents 
   table:put dict_Opinion ? precision new_op_a1 4
   ask res2 [table:put dict_Opinion ? precision new_op_a2 4]]]
```

Until here, everything works fine... I tried to write new_op_a1 and new_op_a2 to a patch-own new_op, but this changes only the color of the patch, turtles are located on.

```
   set new_op ((new_op_a1 + new_op_a2) / 2)
   set pcolor scale-color white new_op 0 1
```

Comment: What is your question? You state that you think you need to write the table  from turtle to patch context, but you don't actually tell us what you want to do. You say that the code colours the patches the turtles are located on. Is there something else you want to do?

Comment: So far I have for each turtle a table that stores a specific opinion (value) per patchID  (key). I want to make a colored representation of the world to display differences in the average opinions. First, I'd like to calculate the average of all opinions per patchID. Second, I'd like to assign this average opinion as patch value. Third, I'd like to make a colored representation from dark (close to 1) to bright (close to 0)

Comment: If I understand correctly, each turtle has an opinion and you are trying to use those opinions to colour patches. The problem is that some patches don't have turtles and therefore the patch is not being coloured. Is this correct? If so, what colour do you expect the patches without turtles to be? After all, they don't have turtles, so there are no opinions on which to calculate the average.

Comment: And to answer the only question you have actually asked, the way to change contexts is to use the `ask` procedure. That is, if you want patches to do something `ask patches [commands]`. I think using tables is forcing you into very awkward code.

Comment: The colour of the patches (key) should be in a gradiënt according to the  average opinion (value) all turtles have about that patch.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't right because i don't really understand how you access a particular turtle's opinion about a particular patch, but the structure should be like this

```
patches-own
[ ...
  what-turtles-think
  ...
]

ask patches
[ set what-turtles-think mean [opinion about myself] of turtles
  set pcolor scale-color red what-turtles-think 0 1
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem:

```
;; add two new variable to patches-own
patches-own [... a b ...]

to patch_avg_op
  ;;calculate  the sum of the opinion of all turtles
  ask turtles [
  foreach table:keys dict_Opinion [
  let c table:get dict_Opinion ?
  let d patches with [plabel = ?]
  ask c [
  set a a + c
    ]
   ]
  ]

  ;; calculate the average and put it in patch variable b  
  let nr_of_turtles count turtles
  ask patches [
  set b (a / nr_of_turtles)
  set a 0
  ]
end

to color-patches
  ask patches [ set pcolor scale-color black b 0 1] 
end
```